# Traefik 2.0 - Path router rule not working with docker labels

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I setup a GraphQL playground listening on port 4000.

So I added the following Traefik labels:

```
graphql:
  restart: unless-stopped
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true
    - "traefik.http.routers.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.rule=Host(`graphql.${CI_ENVIRONMENT_HOST}`)"
    - traefik.http.routers.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
    - traefik.http.services.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.loadbalancer.server.port=4000
```

This is working when I try to get `graphql.site.com`.

Now I want it to match `site.com/graphql`, so I changed the router label to this:

```
"traefik.http.routers.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.rule=Host(`${CI_ENVIRONMENT_HOST}`) && Path(`/graphql`)"
```

And with this configuration, I have a 404 error on `site.com/graphql`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is there a backend listening on  on the path `/graphql`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion there is no backend application listening on the path `/graphql`.

**Solution 1:**

Make backend application (GraphQL) listen on path `/graphql`.

Probably you should also use `` PathPrefix(`/graphql`) `` instead of `` Path(`/graphql`) ``

**Solution2:**

Use traefik `StripPrefix`, which *removes prefixes from the path **before** forwarding the request*.

Use these labels.:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.rule=Host(`${CI_ENVIRONMENT_HOST}`)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.stripprefix-graphql.stripprefix.prefixes=/graphql"
- "traefik.http.routers.${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}-${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-graphql.middlewares=stripprefix-graphql@docker"
```

In case the backend is serving assets (e.g., images or Javascript files) you need to implement additional changes on your backend:
More info here: https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the issue! I added the `/graphql` on my graphql server, works now.

Answer (score 0):

**How does `Path('')` work?**

(the traefik docs dont explain it)

I'd like to create a traefik ingress rule that finds a substring in a host name, e.g. I would like to match *api* in all 3 these examples:

```
mysite.com/subroute1/api/get
mysite.com/subroute2/api/post
mysite.com/subroute2/api/post
```

PathPrefix will not work because the prefix is different for subroute1, subroute2 and subroute3.

Can I use `Path('/api')`, will it work for all 3 subroutes? (or isn't there something like a *PathContains('/api')*)?